# Building opencv project with cmake fails - 'libopencv_videostab.so.3.1.0' needed

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I've got several opencv projects that compile on in Windows and I am now trying to build them in Ubuntu with no success.  They all behave the same, every source file builds fine and then the last source file, main.cpp, has the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.1.0', needed by 'main'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I thought was kind of strange is the other source files include the opencv libraries as well and have no errors, for some reason it doesn't error until main.cpp.  However, the error points me to the issue that '/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.1.0' does not exist.  Indeed it does not, it is located at '/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.3.1.0' instead.  I'm sure this is related to my earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813325/building-and-installing-opencv-3-1-on-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment66920707_39813325), but we're talking about two different directories, and I'm not sure what variable needs to be changed to correct this build issue.  Any ideas?

g++ version: 5.4.0 20160609
CMake version: 3.5.1
Ubuntu 16.04

One of my CMakeLists.txt

```
#####################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) 
project (OpenCVTest)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable (main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
#####################################
```